# External link recognized as a route path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes, sinatra, haml

Using Haml, Sinatra.
I set a path to an external link like the code below, and when I click the link,Sinatra takes me to '/www.test.com'.

```
%a{:href => "www.shunsukekohari.com"} test
```

Comment: nice way to get hits on your website! lol.  see answer below

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard anchor tag and href uses relative path unless you include a protocol so try:

```
%a{:href => "http://www.shunsukekohari.com"} test
```